# how to display image in fullsize in UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

i am currently working in welcome screen.
for that i have take UiPageViewController.
i have download demo from appcode
link  is : [UIPageViewController](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/)

but when i download demo image is displaying like this.

[image: Demo]

my requirement is i want to display images in fullsize
what to do please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on that code change the height for e.g

```
 // Change the size of page view controller
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height + 30 ); it is by default -30 change to any one of + 30 or else
```

you get the output as

[image]

**updated answer**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 // Override point for customization after application launch.
 //    UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
//    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
//    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

return YES;
}
```

or else just change `pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];` **clearColor**

**Update- 2**

**Step-1**

```
// hide your PageControl in Appdelegate 

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 // Override point for customization after application launch.
 //    UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
//    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
//    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

return YES;
}
```

**Step-2**

on your pageConttroller Declaration View Controller do like

```
@interface SurveyViewController (){
UIPageControl *pagecontrol;
NSInteger currentIndex;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
currentIndex = 0;
 [self setupPageControl];
}

- (void)setupPageControl{
pagecontrol = [UIPageControl  appearance];
pagecontrol.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pagecontrol.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = APPBGCOLOR;
pagecontrol.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:pageControl];


}


- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController{
return currentIndex;
}


- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
    return nil;
}

index--;
 currentIndex = index;
[self.pageControl setCurrentPage:index];
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
 NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

if (index == NSNotFound) {
    return nil;
}

index++;
if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
    return nil;
}
 currentIndex = index;
  [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:index];
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: i want pagecontrol in bottom.

Comment: you need the custom pagecontrol

Comment: Thank you for quick response.can you please tell me custom library using XIB.it would be great help

Comment: @KrutarthPatel - samething you need in Xib

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the page is default in page view controller then how can we hide the page control.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i do not want to go with third party.can you plz give me solution?

Comment: oh UIpageController is native is not thir party

Comment: Yes i know but my question is not solved.image is not displying zoom

Comment: bro if you need then use with your custom images its shows with scaleAspectFit

Comment: @SaurabhJain - tanx my bro

Comment: how can i send my code here to check. my error is image is not displaying zoom\

Comment: how to give project here.

Comment: attach in drop box and give the link

Comment: @KrutarthPatel set page controller frame according to the Anbu Sir answer Every thing work fine

Comment: dropbox access is not here. but i tried this code my pageviewcontroller is not displaying after i add this line'

Comment: in viewdidload i added line
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height + 30 );

Comment: and which one not displaying bro

Comment: @KrutarthPatel - check the Updated-2 answer

Comment: thank you brother for support.one request can you upload code on dropbox?i will check?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik How can i contact with you? I want to learn some concept by you.

Comment: @SaurabhJain - welcome bro, I am not a genious compare to google, its ok my number +91 8754 846 846

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thank you for your positive response.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i am stuck in another issue.can you help?waiting for your reply

Comment: @KrutarthPatel - sorry for delay reply, yes bro

Comment: Thanks for reply.
can you plz go through this question.i am getting alignment issues.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342311/receipt-alignment-is-not-working-properly-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment66015676_39342311

Comment: @KrutarthPatel - which question bro

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342311/receipt-alignment-is-not-working-properly-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment66015676_39342311

Comment: That conditions is not fix.i just give an example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327611/how-to-delete-all-items-if-i-delete-one-of-them-in-tableview?noredirect=1#comment65994173_39327611

Comment: This question is still open.please go through it

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Waiting for your response