# How to delete all items if i delete one of them in tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I Have two `collectionView` 
one is for main items and other is for Sub Items

Main Item we can consider as iPhone

Sub Items we can consider as headphone of apple

so we can say this two items “One Group”

both items are adding at DidSelectMethod and displaying in tableView

i have one option of delete this item

my requirement is if i delete any of one item from this group my all tableview data should be cleared

Here is the Code i am using to delete Product

//Define Button Action in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.btnDelete.addTarget(self, action:#selector(ViewController.btnDeleteTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
cell.btnDelete.tag = indexPath.row
```

//Button Action

```
func btnDeleteTapped(sender: UIButton){

  self.arrProductCart.removeObjectAtIndex(sender.tag)
  self.tblCart.reloadData()
}
```

MainProduct Array

```
(
    {
    "addtional_price" = 0;
    "barcode_image" = ".png";
    "cart_unique_id" = 6;
    "chicken_product" = all;
    "created_by" = 2;
    "created_date" = "2015-11-19 21:39:24";
    "deleted_date" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    ids = 151;
    isFromMain = 1;
    "is_deleted" = 0;
    "is_has_addtional_price" = 0;
    "parent_product_unique_id" = 6;
    "product_id" = 53;
    "product_name" = "Black Pepper Chicken";
    "product_parent_id" = 0;
    "product_price" = "7.9";
    "sub_category_type" = "";
    "update_date" = "2016-06-22 17:54:53";
    "updated_by" = 7;
  "parent_product_unique_id" = 6
}
```

)

SubProduct Array

```
     {
    "created_by" = 2;
    "created_date" = "2015-11-19 23:11:37";
    "deleted_date" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    ids = 157;
    isFromMain = 0;
    "product_category_id" = 16;
    "product_description" = "Potato";
    "product_id" = 59;
    "product_name" = "Potato";
    "product_parent_id" = 0;
    "product_price" = 2;
    "product_quantity" = 0;
    "sub_category_type" = s;
    "product_unique_id" = 6
}
```

it that any solution to do this ?

Comment: You need to update the dataSource with it.

Comment: How does your array look like? And are you using multiple sections?

Comment: @Mr.UB you want to know all Parameters?

Comment: yes, structure of the array would be helpful.

Comment: @NDoc Right Now Deleting one item from TableView at index.Yes it is giving all delating of data which i add

Comment: Suppose if we buy iphone so we can get its headphone free. so this two products are now we can say one group. if i am deleting one item from  this group than all data should be deleted.
This is my Requirement

Comment: Please check Updates Question

Comment: @KrutarthPatel In other words - if you delete Apple from your data source, all of your subordinated items (headphones, iphone) will also be removed? But how are your collectionviews related? You haven't explained it though

Comment: @pedrouan Yes thats my requirement

Comment: @KrutarthPatel So please explain a bit better, how your data source is made? We need a structure of creation, not just the output from the response. And what is the relation between those two collectionviews like?

Comment: i am adding json response in Sqlite.to retrive SubProducts from Product table i am using "sub_category_type" Parameter.

Comment: Found any Solution for this? :)

Comment: Hello.i really needs help.already deadline start

Comment: As per my understanding, you have one array for both collectionViews so just call ArrProduct.removeAllObjects() and after that relaod both collectionViews or Tables tbl1.reloadData() and tbl2.reloadData(). 
And also remove it from sqlite.

Comment: @AadilAli i will check and will update here.thank you for response

Comment: one question : can you explain for this my requirement is if i delete any of one item from this group my all tableview data should be cleared

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  In other words - if you delete Apple from your data source, all of your subordinated items (headphones, iphone) will also be removed

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik not all data , but group should be cleared if i delete main product

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Got it?

Comment: @NiravD Please check updated question

Comment: @NiravD parent_product_unique_id from main array and product_unique_id from sub array is same.

Comment: @NiravD now what to do

Comment: Check edited question.i add main and sub aray

Comment: @NiravD Exactly i want to remove all subitems if i remove main item from tableview.

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Ok, then what is the name of your subArray, from your code it is look a like your main Array name is `ArrProduct` .

Comment: @NiravD when i am adding product to cart. i am adding main and sub array to ArrProduct.

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Can you please add code of on which basis you will delete item from Main Array?

Comment: @NiravD i added code to delete in question. and i add main and sub array to  ArrProduct. and display data in tableview using this ArrProduct.

Comment: @KrutarthPatel I am asking is in delete action how i know which item is you are deleting from mainArray?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127683/discussion-between-krutarth-patel-and-nirav-d).

Comment: @NiravD plz check discussion.i post images

Comment: @NiravD Any solution for this?

Comment: @KrutarthPatel I think Answer given by Rajat is what you want

Comment: @NiravD Yes.now i will work to make dynamic.

Comment: @NiravD Thanks for support

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Welcome :)