# Receipt alignment is not working properly in swift

Tags: ios, swift, epson, receipt

I am currently printing receipt from my data
when i print my receipt alignment data is not working properly

i think that i should apply start index and end index to string

because my product name length is different 
So i apply this code to check length of string

here is screenshot of Receipt

[image]

you can see in receipt alignment is wrong

Here is my code to give alignment and receipt

```
   if       ProductName.characters.count > 13 {let subStr = ProductName[ProductName.startIndex.advancedBy(0)... ProductName.characters.count(13)]
            strtext.appendString(String (format: "%@ %@                       %@\n", sQuantity,subStr,s))
            textData.appendString(strtext as String)
        }
```

my requirement is first quantity,name and price should be come
My receipt alignment is not proper

anyone can help me solve this issue?

Comment: increase width of each and make right alignment to all will fix your issue

Comment: my requirement is left side quantity and product name should come and price should be displayed to right of page

Comment: try this in with out this condition if       ProductName.characters.count > 13

Comment: @KrutarthPatel - I worked on this concept, but Eposn has one option for alignment option , please check once

Comment: Can you show me code in swift ?

Comment: @KrutarthPatel did you manage to find a solution? I am also facing the issue...I still need to look into alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is fine additionally , 
there is the option in `Epson` Printer in

```
enum EposOcAlign {
 EPOS_OC_ALIGN_LEFT = 0,
 EPOS_OC_ALIGN_CENTER,
 EPOS_OC_ALIGN_RIGHT
};
```

the method is invoked as `- (int) addTextAlign:(int)align;` use align type as **center** and try once

Comment: Thank you for response.will check

Comment: @KrutarthPatel - finally we do for little bit changes in space in that your code, sorry I also did this in 1 year back I forgot most of the things

Comment: means.where you change

Comment: @KrutarthPatel - in this one  strtext.appendString(String (format: "%@ %@                       %@\n", sQuantity,subStr,s))